# ExtJs combobox stores loading and form

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a problem with comboboxes on my form.
The problem is that when I load form data (with `form.loadRecord`) **sometimes** comboboxes are empty even though I know that the model has the data.

When I look into Firebug I can see that the combobox stores are loaded after the record has been loaded. I thinks this is the reason – the combobox stores are loaded later then record is loaded.

This is how I set combobox stores:

```
    //All stores have autoload:true configuration.
    var possessionGroundsStore = Ext.create('path.to.store');
    var vehicleTypesStore = Ext.create('path.to.store');
    var usePurposesStore = Ext.create('path.to.store');
    this.editView = Ext.create('path.to.view');
    this.editView.getPossessionGroundsField().store = possessionGroundsStore;
    this.editView.getVehicleTypeIdComboBox().store = vehicleTypesStore;
    this.editView.getUsePurposeField().store = usePurposesStore;

    //later
    this.editView.loadRecord(record);
```

Is there a common way to solve this problem?

The only way I can see now is to use `store.load` callbacks in every combobox store 
and then execute loadRecord after all stores were loaded, but it seems complex.

Any help?

**UPDATE:**
When `form.loadRecord` is called it internally calls `field.setValue()`.
So, the point is: combobox store have to be populated before `setValue` is called.
If the store is not loaded you will see `valueField` instead of `displayField`.

Comment: Try with triggerAction: 'all' for combobox property

Answer (score 5):

The *default* config for comboboxes will trigger a store load when they get expanded for the first time after being created.

That will happen for any combobox unless you give it a `queryMode: 'local'` config. In other words the default combobox config almost always completes loading it's store **after** the component is created. For that reason, it seems strange to me that your combos are having a hard time with being loaded too late, maybe they are being loaded too early with `autoLoad: true`

However, I don't run into the same problem you have because I usually set-up my comboboxes with `queryMode: 'local'` and pre-load the stores for them right at the app initialization stage. I do that because my combo stores are usually all reference stores that could get used in many different views in my app. I don't recreate the store when I create a combo component, I just get a reference to the already existing and loaded reference store with `Ext.getStore('ComboStoreId')`. You could try setting up your app like that.

If you don't want to do that, you could also try removing the `autoLoad: true` config from your combo stores, then call `yourComboStore.load()` *after* you call `loadRecord`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your way(the second one) but no luck. See my update.